# Azure SQL PaaS server\database delete?

Tags: sql-server, azure, paas

I want to phase out the  Azure SQL server. However I don't want to delete it the first time, I would prefer to manually pause (avoiding it to auto-start in case of some connection) and after 30 days, delete the server.

How to safely keep the Azure database backup files for 30 days and then delete this server?

Answer (score 0):

> How to safely keep the Azure database backup files for 30 days and then delete this server?

Move it down to the [Serverless](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/serverless-tier-overview#:%7E:text=Serverless%20is%20a%20compute%20tier%20for%20single%20databases,for%20the%20amount%20of%20compute%20used%20per%20second.) tier and pause it, so you pay only for the storage, or you can also delete the database and rely on the ability to [restore a deleted database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/recovery-using-backups#deleted-database-restore).

Or you can opt-in to [Long Term Backup Retention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/long-term-retention-overview).

Or you can [export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-export) the database to a .bacpac file (not a .bak SQL Server backup).

Comment: I have general-purpose gen 5 serverless. My backups policy is for 7 days. if I delete the server, how do I restore the database? how do I see where is it storing backups (Azure storage) and how to move those backup files to where I have access to it even after deleting the server.

Comment: See updated answer.